# How to set ulimits in Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, openldap, ulimit

I normally use `pam_limits.so` and `/etc/security/limits.conf` to set [ulimits](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Ulimit) on file size, CPU time, etc. for the regular users logging in to my server running Ubuntu. What is the best way of doing something similar with Solaris 10?

I think it is done using `/etc/system`, but I have no idea what to add to the file or indeed if it is the correct file. I'm particularly interested in setting up `ulimit -f` without going down the `.profile` route.

Answer (score 5):

On Solaris you can set this parameter to be a hard or soft limit system-wide OR you can do the same for a specific application so that it has the correct number of open file descriptors in its run-time space.

To make it a system-wide change, edit `/etc/system` with following entries

```
# Hard limit on file descriptors for single process
set rlim_fd_max = 4096

# Soft limit on the file descriptors for a single process
set rlim_fd_cur = 1024
```

NOTE: without setting `rlim_fd_max` as shown above, the default value for file descriptors or nofiles is half of the `rlim_fd_cur` value. So, it's best to set them both.

If you are using a Solaris project for an application space like Oracle Database, you can set the max file descriptors in the project by:

```
projadd -U oracle -K “process.max-file-descriptor=(priv,4096,deny)” user.oracle
```

Additionally, you can set it using `ulimit` directly in an application's owner's shell startup file.  For example, it is possible to establish max file descriptors by setting `ulimit` in the `.profile` of the web server's owner to `ulimit -s 32768` and calling that from the startup/shutdown script.

As you can see there are lots of options and ways of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

It's also worth mentioning plimit. This can view or set limits on already running processes.

```
# plimit 7028
7028:   /usr/lib/gconfd-2 18
   resource              current         maximum
  time(seconds)         unlimited       unlimited
  file(blocks)          unlimited       unlimited
  data(kbytes)          unlimited       unlimited
  stack(kbytes)         10240           unlimited
  coredump(blocks)      unlimited       unlimited
  nofiles(descriptors)  512             65536
  vmemory(kbytes)       unlimited       unlimited
```

Answer (score 2):

> it is possible to establish max file descriptors by setting ulimit in the .profile of the web server's owner to ulimit -s 32768

ulimit -n 32768  - is correct

Answer (score 1):

You may find this link interesting: [Tuning the Operating System](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19644-01/817-5051/pt_tuningos.html)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/archives/4204-Less-known-Solaris-Features-Resource-Management-Part-1-Introduction.html) link has detailed info about how to use Solaris 10 "projects".

[This](http://www.c0t0d0s0.org/pages/lksfbook.html) PDF has all the parts in one file. The stuff relevant to this question is on page 59.