# How to increase a soft limit of a stack size for processes run by some user (uid) on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris-10

Our enterprise runs on Oracle Tuxedo 10, under Solaris 10. As a result of some recent development (customization source code all across the system was changed by extending sizes of local variables which are declared in C functions) we run into Stack Overflow problem from time to time (depending on how long the functions calls chain is).
As a work-around we decided on increasing a soft limit size of a stack (for all Tuxedo processes running by single user). Considering to use ulimit, /etc/project etc. 
Clear & short step-by-step instruction for our on-site support team on how to extend a stack size (per-user) in Solaris 10 would be very appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Peter Mortensen in the link bellow answers this and covers the step by step instructions too:
[How to set ulimits in Solaris 10](https://serverfault.com/questions/21417/how-to-set-ulimits-in-solaris-10)

IMHO the fastest way for on-site support would be:

1.Become the target user
2.`echo "ulimit -s 32768" >> ~/.profile`
3.Relog and restart the application